# Boot error "Platform does not support this image''

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have dual boot and when I choose Windows it starts without problems, but when I choose Ubuntu (19.10) it shows the following error messages:

> Platform does not support this image
>   Failed to read header: Unsupported
>   Failed to load image: Unsupported
>   start_image() returned Unsupported

Then it does not boot.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with boot repair tool. To use it you need a bootable USB pendrive, with Ubuntu on it.

After booting, open a terminal and enter these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```